# What is the correct way to schedule jobs in express?

Tags: node.js, express, scheduled-tasks

Coming from a rails background where DelayedJob/sidekiq integrate very simply with the Rails application, I am a little unsure about how to do the same with Express. I found [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) in a few examples with node, but I am unsure about the right app structure/convention.

What I am trying to achieve is picking up datetimes from a file and on those values execute a particular function. I thought a cron job/scheduler would be a good way to implement this, but I am open to suggestions!

Would love to know the right way [in terms of packages and project structure] to do this in express!

Comment: It's not very clear what your need is.  The simplest would be to just calculate how many ms from now the event should occur and use `setTimeout()`.  If you want a more persistent scheduler that will persist the schedule to disk and reload it when the server restarts, then you're probably looking for one of the many cron packages.  There is no particular "right" way.  It depends entirely upon your needs.

Comment: your question is a little opinion based but I think this is the better library https://github.com/smrchy/rsmq unless you want to implement your own message queue or use something mainstream like kafka

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for replying, I have added a little more information in the question, is that helpful? In essence I have a set of datetimes that I need to execute a function on. I am trying to find the right package (like the cron packages that you mentioned) + the right project structure for this.

Comment: @C.Gochev thanks for pointing that out, I'm taking a look at it! Is there any good practices that you would suggest in terms of project structure for queues in express?

Comment: Well, it is off-topic here on stackoverflow to ask for recommendations of third party packages.  You could try the software recommendations forum.

Comment: @jfriend00, got it, thanks!